# Boost.Python Error when use class

Tags: boost-python, clang++

I got an error `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'` when I use a class in Boost.Python (I could run simple "Hello, world").

**Environment**

- macOS Sierra
- I use `pyenv-virtualenv`

  - Python 3.6.0
  - `$ source activate py36`
- I installed boost-python via homebrew

  1. `$pyenv global py36`
  2. `$brew install boost`
  3. `$brew install boost-python --with-python3`

---

**Code**

This is the simple code I tried (`test.cpp`).

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;

int main(){

}

class accumulator {
public:
    int operator()(int v) {
        v_ += v;
        return v_;
    }

    int value() const {
        return v_;
    }

private:
    int v_;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{

    class_<accumulator>("accumulator")
        .def("__call__",
             &accumulator::operator())
        .add_property("value", &accumulator::value)
        ;
}
```

---

**makefile**

```
CC = clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
PYTHON_ROOT = /usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.0
PYTHON = -lpython3.6m -lboost_python3

# location of the Boost Python include files and library

BOOST_INC = /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/lib

# compile mesh classes
TARGET = test

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) $(TARGET).o $(PYTHON) -I$(PYTHON_ROOT)/include/python3.6m  -L$(BOOST_LIB) -L$(PYTHON_ROOT)/lib  -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    $(CC)  -I$(PYTHON_ROOT)/include/python3.6m -I$(BOOST_INC) -c $(TARGET).cpp
```

---

**Compile**

```
$ make
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++  -I/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/include/python3.6m -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/include -c test.cpp
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ test.o -lpython3.6m -lboost_python3 -I/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/include/python3.6m  -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python/1.64.0/lib -L/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib  -o test.so

$ python
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 28 2016, 23:31:45)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import test
>>> a = test.accumulator()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

---

I did the same question in [Japanese](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/37357/%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E9%9A%9B%E3%81%AEboost-python%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC). I will translate the solution if I get it in either one of them.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437769/boost-python-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype) seems to be the same problem. It seems you need to either build boost_python against python 3.6.0 or build your extension using the exact same version as the one used in brew (the latest seems to be 3.6.2). Disclaimer: I'm just speculating, I have no experience with this problem.