# boost python after compile and run give me a TypeError in the __init__

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have compiled successfully the following program

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/list.hpp>
#include <boost/python/extract.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { mMsg = msg; }
    void many(boost::python::list msgs) {
        long l = len(msgs);
        std::stringstream ss;
        for (long i = 0; i<l; ++i) {
            if (i>0) ss << ", ";
            std::string s = boost::python::extract<std::string>(msgs[i]);
            ss << s;
        }
        mMsg = ss.str();
    }
    std::string greet() { return mMsg; }
    std::string mMsg;
};

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(classes)
{
    class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
        .def("many", &World::many)
    ;
};
```

When I try to execute the classes module with Python interpreter, I receive the following error:

```
Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Sep 21 2017, 18:29:43)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import classes
>>> classes.World()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NoneType'
```

I am using:

- osx 10.13
- python 3.6 anaconda
- boost 1.65.1
- clang 4.0.1

I compiled the program with the following clang++ command:

```
clang++ -o classes.so -shared -fPIC\
        -L/usr/local/anaconda/lib \
        -lboost_python3 \
        -lpython3.6m \
        -I/usr/local/anaconda/include \
        -I/usr/local/anaconda/include/python3.6m \
        classes.cpp
```

I checked that my *.so file was linked correctly:

```
> otool -L classes.so
classes.so:
    @rpath/libboost_python3.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    @rpath/libpython3.6m.dylib (compatibility version 3.6.0, current version 3.6.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 400.9.0)
```

I have already checked the following question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437769](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20437769/boost-python-init-should-return-none-not-nonetype), however, it seems that in my case I have linked my program against the good Python library (the same the Python installation using to import the module).

How do I solve it?

Comment: Here's my data point, [live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcbd3e36344a27a3)

Comment: Having the same exact issue.